# How do I install the latest version of iTunes in Ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: 16.04, itunes

I use iTunes on Windows and recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1. How can I install the same iTunes version in Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: you can install a slightly older version of itunes, but not the latest, run `sudo apt install playonlinux` then once that is done, open play on linux, select the install button, wait until it is done loading, select itunes, then follow the instructions onscreen

Answer (score 1):

The only *somewhat* **RELIABLE** way to run iTunes on a Ubuntu host, is to install Virtualbox with a Windows guest OS. Then install the standard latest version of iTunes in Windows.

Forget about trying Wine or Playonlinux, etc.